# Dynamic postgis raster data type serving from geoserver

Tags: postgis, raster, geoserver, wms, wfs

I have PostGIS database, which I am using to store raster image as raster datatype. A table has column date, raster, and other property. There are more than 30 tables in the database. The database tables are updated, where the raster for the particular time is replaced with the latest available and/or new rows are added.

I am doing little research on if I can use GeoServer to store the dynamic PostGIS DB and render as WMS/WFS for the web client. I need to be able to perform clipping, filter particular row based on date and style those data. What is the best approach to do this in geoserver? I followed [postgis raster](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/postgisraster.html) in geoserver, but it seems I need to generate pyramid and store them in a separate table using Image Mosaic JDBC. Since data are dynamic, is there another way without exporting the raster?

Comment: Not sure, you'll get WFS to work with raster data, more likely you should use WCS

Answer (score 1):

[This page in the GeoServer documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/postgisraster.html) says that you can do it, but you need to use the [Image Mosaic JDBC extension](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaicjdbc.html).

Here's a tutorial: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic-jdbc/imagemosaic-jdbc_tutorial.html

Comment: Hi Alex - Thanks for the reply. I am using the same tutorial. With this tutorial, it looks like I need to export the raster data type in PostGIS to raster format and then prepare the pyramid and the tiles. Isn't that so? Since the data are dynamic, so I guess I should run a cron job to do this (convert into the raster, prepare pyramid and tiles and update the PostGIS table that holds this info). I am looking for more simpler method than this.

Comment: Hi @Biplov, I think that, since you've already got data in the database, you should be able to skip to the later section: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic-jdbc/imagemosaic-jdbc_tutorial.html#configuring-the-new-map